# how to scrape article from a web with credential by using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I usually do a web scrapping from a public website with scrapy, but this time I need to scrape article from a private website that requires credential. I have the credential with me, but I still don't get how to put the username and password into my scrapy script.

This is what I usually do on my script:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class EnergyGeneralNews(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'energygeneralnews'
    start_urls = ['https://oilprice.com/Energy/Energy-General/Page-'+str(x)+'.html' for x in range(1,18)]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//*[@class="categoryArticle__content"]/a/@href'):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link.get(),
                callback=self.parse_item
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'date': response.xpath('//*[@class="article_byline"]/text()[2]').re(r'\w+?\s\d\d,\s\d{4}'),
            'category': response.xpath('(//*[@itemprop="name"])[3]/text()').get(),
            'title': response.xpath('//*[@class="singleArticle__content"]/h1/text()').get(),
            'text':''.join([x.get().strip() for x in response.xpath('//*[@id="article-content"]//p//text()')])
            }
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(energygeneralnews)
    process.start()
```

where should I put the credential into the script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the url in the example the same site you want to use the credentials on?

Comment: no, the url I try to scrape that requires the credential is https://petromindo.com/. Can you check on it? @Alexander